# Excel: find the cell that another formula found its "answer" in

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I made a formula that searches an array to return a value, and now I want excel to "show its work" and tell me in which cell it found that value. I've been fighting with `MATCH` and `ADDRESS` but so far have been only able to return the value's *position within the array* and not its absolute cell reference.

As a secondary goal, I want to take that cell reference and look one cell down and one cell to the left, then return whatever value it finds there. I don't know if that's a goofy way of doing it but that's my idea so far. Any better methods would be appreciated.

The actual file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78225/test_sheet.xlsx

EDIT: the formula I'm using, which is returning the right value but I want to find that value's cell reference: `{=MIN(IF($D$1:$DG$1="food",IF(D2:DG2<>"",D2:DG2)))}`

Comment: You should really post the formula you are using and which part you want to look up (expected results) as it would be easier to provide an answer.  I've listed a generic answer below that should get you most of the way there.

Comment: I tried `CELL` with the array-entered formula `{=MIN(IF($D$1:$DG$1="food",IF(D2:DG2<>"",D2:DG2)))}`, but it throws an error and won't even let me enter it. Did you take a look at the actual file?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with the **CELL** function as shown below.

```
=CELL("address",your formula here)
```

For looking to the left or the right of the answer look up the offset function.

**EDIT**

I don't know of a way to do this directly with a min function I think you would need to look it back up in the table

Your formula in: B2

```
   {=MIN(IF($D$1:$DG$1="food",IF(D2:DG2<>"",D2:DG2)))}
```

Lookup formula

```
=CELL("address",INDEX($D$2:$DG$2,MATCH("food",$D$1:$DG$1,0)*MATCH(B2,$D$2:$DG$2,0)))
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the formula as you described. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This would work if you were using something like a lookup, or index function that returns the value of an individual cell it won't work for the formula you are using

Comment: `=CELL("address",INDEX($D$2:$DG$2,MATCH("food",$D$1:$DG$1,0)*MATCH(B2,$D$2:$DG$2,0)))` used on `{=MIN(IF($D$1:$DG$1="food",IF(D2:DG2<>"",D2:DG2)))}` (which reads "2005) returns "$G$2"; G2 contains "2006". Am I missing something here?